# How to create a Java name generator using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I need to create a name generator that uses for loops and if/else selection to generate the name. Input will be stored in separate char[] for each of the four words you enter.

I am currently at a lost, so far I have only coded the below but it does not use for loops or arrays.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameGenerator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Enter your first name: ");

        String firstname = input.nextLine();

        firstname = firstname.substring(0,3);
        System.out.printf("Enter your last name: ");

        String lastname = input.nextLine();
        lastname = lastname.substring(0,2);

        System.out.printf("Enter your mother's maiden name: ");
        String mothersname = input.nextLine();
        mothersname = mothersname.substring(0,2);

        System.out.printf("Enter the name of the city in which you were born: ");
        String cityname = input.nextLine();
        cityname = cityname.substring(0,3);

        String GenFirstName = (firstname  + lastname); 
        String GenLastName = (mothersname + cityname);
        System.out.println("May the force be with you, " + GenFirstName + " " + GenLastName );
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of an input and the expected output for this program. It'll help people understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure what it is you are really after, but this is what I came up with.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameGenerator
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("Enter your first name: ");
    char[] firstname;
        firstname = input.next().toCharArray();

    System.out.printf("Enter your last name: ");
    char[] lastname;
    lastname = input.next().toCharArray();

    System.out.printf("Enter your mother's maiden name: ");
    char[] mothersname;
    mothersname = input.next().toCharArray();

    System.out.printf("Enter the name of the city in which you were born: ");
    char[] cityname;
    cityname = input.next().toCharArray();

    String GenFirstName = "";
    String GenLastName = "";

    for(int count = 0; count <= 3; count++){
        GenFirstName += firstname[count];
        GenLastName += mothersname[count];
    }

    for(int count = 0; count <= 3; count++){
        GenFirstName += lastname[count];
        GenLastName += cityname[count];
    }

    System.out.println("May the force be with you, " + GenFirstName + " " + GenLastName );
}

}
```

UPDATE
Here is the command line arguments version.

```
    public class NameGenerator
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    char[] firstname;
        firstname = args[0].toCharArray();

    char[] lastname;
    lastname = args[1].toCharArray();

    char[] mothersname;
    mothersname = args[2].toCharArray();

    char[] cityname;
    cityname = args[3].toCharArray();

    String GenFirstName = "";
    String GenLastName = "";

    for(int count = 0; count <= 3; count++){
        GenFirstName += firstname[count];
        GenLastName += mothersname[count];
    }

    for(int count = 0; count <= 3; count++){
        GenFirstName += lastname[count];
        GenLastName += cityname[count];
    }

    System.out.println("May the force be with you, " + GenFirstName + " " + GenLastName );
}

}
```

Comment: This is how I would do it based on what you already said. Where you told to use command line arguments?

Comment: There you go! Added it to the original answer. Remember to accept my answer :)

Comment: How are you currently entering it?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
   at NameGenerator.main(NameGenerator.java:10)

Comment: The last name you are using is less than 4 characters long. 

Since the code says "for(int count = 0; count **<= 3**; count++)" it loops 4 times, and tries to get the 4th character of the parameter. 

So depending on how many characters you would like to get from the parameters you should change the "<=3" to a different value such as "<3"

Comment: Don't worry about it. Can you show me exactly what commands you are typing into the command prompt please?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with BlueJ... Try putting the quotes around each parameter and separating them with a comma like: {"John", "Doe", "Smith", "Toronto"}

Comment: You're welcome. An easy way I think to do it would be to make last name and city name: lastname = args[1].toLowerCase().toCharArray(); and cityname = args[3].toLowerCase().toCharArray(); So that when it populates the area the second half of the names are all lower case. There may be another way to do it but I'm not sure.

Comment: What order are you entering the data in?